# Hibernate LocalDateTime and Mysql datetime conversation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, datetime

I have a `datetime` field in MySql database and corresponding `LocalDateTime` field in Hibernate entity. It's possible to change application timezone in runtime using `TimeZone.setDefault` function and ORM applies offset to `LocalDateTime` field. Is there any way to force Hibernate show the same date as stored in database?